# Multiprocess Daemon Not Terminating on Parent Exit

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a Python 2.7 multiprocessing Process which will not exit on parent process exit. I've set the daemon flag which should force it to exit on parent death. The docs state that:

"When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes."

```
p = Process(target=_serverLaunchHelper, args=args)
p.daemon = True
print p.daemon # prints True
p.start()
```

When I terminate the parent process via a kill command the daemon is left alive and running (which blocks the port on the next run). The child process is starting a SimpleHttpServer and calling `serve_forever` without doing anything else. My guess is that the "attempts" part of the docs means that the blocking server process is stopping process death and it's letting the process get orphaned as a result. I could have the child push the serving to another Thread and have the main thread check for parent process id changes, but this seems like a lot of code to just replicate the daemon functionality.

Does someone have insight into why the daemon flag isn't working as described? This is repeatable on windows8 64 bit and ubuntu12 32 bit vm.

A boiled down version of the process function is below:

```
def _serverLaunchHelper(port)
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", port), Handler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes.

The key word here is "attempts". Also, "exits".

Depending on your platform and implementation, it may be that the only way to get daemonic child processes terminated is to do so explicitly. If the parent process exits normally, it gets a chance to do so explicitly, so everything is fine. But if the parent process is terminated abruptly, it doesn't.

For CPython in particular, if you look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#l288), terminating daemonic processes is handled the same way as joining non-daemonic processes: by walking `active_children()` in an [`atexit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) function. So, your daemons will be killed if and only if your `atexit` handlers get to run. And, as that module's docs say:

> Note: the functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when `os._exit()` is called.

Depending on how you're killing the parent, you might be able to work around this by adding a signal handler to intercept abrupt termination. But you might not—e.g., on POSIX, `SIGKILL` is not intercept able, so if you `kill -9 $PARENTPID`, this isn't an option.

Another option is to kill the process group, instead of just the parent process. For example, if your parent has PID 12345, `kill -- -12345` on linux will kill it and all of its children (assuming you haven't done anything fancy).

Comment: Alright, so if I really want to guarantee that children quit when the parent dies I need to program logic into the children processes to watch for their parents disappearing. Thanks for the clear and quick answer!

Comment: Also, the mp lib uses process.terminate() which is a fairly soft-kill, and then it calls join(), which can hang forever.   I added a 10 second timeout and a kill-9  on failure in there - seems to clean up everything.