# python - terminate child process when script invoked from bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, process, multiprocessing

I have a python script: zombie.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import atexit

def foo():
    while True:
        sleep(10)

@atexit.register
def stop_foo():
    p.terminate()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()

    while True:
        sleep(10)
```

When I run this with `python zombie.py &` and kill the parent process with `kill -2`, the `stop()` is correctly called and both processes terminate.

Now, suppose I have a bash script zombie.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

python zombie.py &

echo "done"
```

And I run `./zombie.sh` from the command line.

Now, `stop()` never gets called when the parent gets killed. If I run `kill -2` on the parent process, nothing happens. `kill -15` or `kill -9` both just kill the parent process, but not the child:

```
[foo@bar ~]$ ./zombie.sh 
done
[foo@bar ~]$ ps -ef | grep zombie | grep -v grep
foo 27220     1  0 17:57 pts/3    00:00:00 python zombie.py
foo 27221 27220  0 17:57 pts/3    00:00:00 python zombie.py
[foo@bar ~]$ kill -2 27220
[foo@bar ~]$ ps -ef | grep zombie | grep -v grep
foo 27220     1  0 17:57 pts/3    00:00:00 python zombie.py
foo 27221 27220  0 17:57 pts/3    00:00:00 python zombie.py
[foo@bar ~]$ kill 27220
[foo@bar ~]$ ps -ef | grep zombie | grep -v grep
foo 27221     1  0 17:57 pts/3    00:00:00 python zombie.py
```

What is going on here? How can I make sure the child process dies with the parent?

Comment: related: [How to make child process die after parent exits?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/284325/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Neither the `atexit` nor the `p.daemon = True` will truely *ensure* that the child process will die with the father.  Receiving a SIGTERM will not trigger the `atexit` routines.

To make sure the child gets killed upon its father's death you will have to install a signal handler in the father.  This way you can react on most signals (SIGQUIT, SIGINT, SIGHUP, SIGTERM, ...) but not on SIGKILL; there simply is no way to react on that signal from within the process which receives it.

Install a signal handler for all useful signals and in that handler kill the child process.

Comment: Installing singal handlers won't "truely ensure" it either. On Linux, there is `prctl()` but it would be an overkill.

Comment: What do you mean by father? The bash script? I have already installed the `atexit.register` in the python script, which should respond to `SIGINT` from `kill -2`.

Comment: No, the father process I referred to is the Python script you started.  By using the `subprocess` module it creates a child process.

Comment: And actually, no, the `atexit` reacts to a controlled exiting of the Python script.  The SIGINT is caught by the interpreter and translated to a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception which then propagates orderly and leads as a result to a controlled termination of the script; thus the `atexit` is triggered.  This will not function anymore if any other signal (which the Python interpreter does not handle this gracefully) terminates the process.

Answer (score 1):

Update: This solution doesn't work for processes killed by a signal.

---

Your child process is not a [zombie](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_446). It is alive.

If you want the child process to be killed when its parent *exits normally* then set `p.daemon = True` before `p.start()`. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing#multiprocessing.Process.daemon):

> When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes.

Looking at [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#l305), it is clear that `multiprocessing` uses `atexit` callback to kill its daemonic children i.e., it won't work if the parent is killed by a signal. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import os
import signal
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process, log_to_stderr
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep

def foo():
    while True:
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    # either kill itself or exit normally in 5 seconds
    if '--kill' in sys.argv:
        Timer(5, os.kill, [os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM]).start()
    else: # exit normally
        sleep(5)
```

#### Output

```
$ python kill-orphan.py
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[INFO/MainProcess] calling terminate() for daemon Process-1
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process Process-1
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
```

Notice *"calling terminate() for daemon"* line.

#### Output (with `--kill`)

```
$ python kill-orphan.py --kill
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
```

The log shows that if the parent is killed by a signal then "atexit" callback is not called (and `ps` shows that the child is alive in this case). See also [Multiprocess Daemon Not Terminating on Parent Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15887994/4279).

Comment: This doesn't work on my system. I'm running `Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon)`.

Comment: @user545424: It fails on my system too (Ubuntu). I'd expected it to work for such signals as `SIGTERM`. It works for `SIGINT` though (`kill -2`).